# Empty parenthesis after "Open Source" header?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On my SO careers CV I have a whole lot of open source projects from my BitBucket page listed; but the header has some parenthesis that don't seem to make a lot of sense:

[image]

It looks like something is supposed to go there? Number of projects maybe?

I see this both in the editor as in the "preview public CV", and its only with this header (all the others don't have any parenthesis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report, this is now fixed. It's intended to show the total number of projects you have on your profile when there's more than we display by default.